# C# Get Keys from Intertwined String Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, string, dictionary

I have a **string dictionary** as shown in below. As you see, keys are **string dates**, but their values are dictionary.

`"{"19-02-2020":{"1":"ABC","2":"DEF"},"20-02-2020":{"1" : "GHI","2" : "JKL","3" : "MNO"},"21-02-2020" : {"1" : "PRS"}}"`

That can be written to be more understandable;

```
"{
  "19-02-2020" : {"1" : "ABC", "2" : "DEF"},
  "20-02-2020" : {"1" : "GHI", "2" : "JKL", "3" : "MNO"},
  "21-02-2020" : {"1" : "PRS"}
 }"
```

How can I get the string dates in string format? I tried to split this string with "," or something more. But it seems impossible because I will get more dates with its dictionary values in the future. Is there any way to get keys from string dictionary?

I want to get an array which contains string dates like `["19-02-2020","20-02-2020","21-02-2020"]`

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could provide a [mcve] with the expected output. Also, this looks like JSON - any reason you're not just parsing it *as* JSON, e.g. using Json.NET to create a JObject?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for warning. I added my expected output. Yes it looks like json but I have to use this with string format.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. *Please* provide one - code we can copy, paste, compile. At the moment it's still unclear what you've really got.

Comment: dictionary has a `Keys` property, you can use it

Comment: Just to get this right, you need all key values from your `Dictionaty<String, Dictionary<String, String>>` and compile them all into a `String[]` array?

Comment: @Wicaledon, do you really have a `string dictionary`, or actually `a string` with that json content? Is the real question "how to parse JSON"?

Comment: @Andrew you can think like I have `string mydict = "{"19-02-2020":{"1":"ABC","2":"DEF"},"20-02-2020":{"1" : "GHI","2" : "JKL","3" : "MNO"},"21-02-2020" : {"1" : "PRS"}}"`

Comment: Then I guess you need to take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your JSON string into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace. It implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`, so you easily get the key as `string`

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var item in jObject) 
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
```

The output will be the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your data is just a **dictionary** with a **string key** and **dictionary value**, you can easily deserialize it (e.g. with Newtonsoft.Json) and extract the values you need.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

```
var deserializedDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(yourString);

// The data you are interested in.
var dates = dict.Keys.ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for answer but for example how can I get the first date? I thought `dates` 's type is array so I tried dates[0] but didn't work

Comment: I made an edit. Just add ```.ToArray()``` to make the keys colleciton an array.